# "<=" not giving expected results in Python

Tags: python, loops

I am teaching myself Python. I have gone through some tutorials and thought I'd write a little program for counting the candles for each of the respective 8 nights of Hanukkah.

```
days = 0
candles = 1

while days <= 8 :
    days = days + 1
    candles = candles + 1
    print ("Day", days,":", candles, "Candles")
```

But the results for this (Python 3.4) are:

```
Day 1 : 2 Candles
Day 2 : 3 Candles
Day 3 : 4 Candles
Day 4 : 5 Candles
Day 5 : 6 Candles
Day 6 : 7 Candles
Day 7 : 8 Candles
Day 8 : 9 Candles
Day 9 : 10 Candles
```

Why didn't it stop at day 8?

Comment: It only checks the condition at the start of an iteration; it doesn't notice that `days == 9` until after the `print`.

Answer (score 1):

Because you `days <= 8` when the loop starts, then you add one to it in the loop. `while` loops don't stop the second the value changes they finish executing the block and then return to the conditional and check if they should keep going.

Answer (score 0):

You are incrementing the value of the variable `days` after the test. When `days` is 8, you increment it to `9` and then you print it.

I would do something like this:

```
days = 1
candles = 2

while days <= 8 :
    print ("Day", days,":", candles, "Candles")
    days = days + 1
    candles = candles + 1
```

Answer (score 0):

If you increase your variables at the end you will get what you want.

```
days = 1
candles = 2

while days <= 8 :

    print ("Day", days,":", candles, "Candles")
    days = days + 1
    candles = candles + 1
```